# Pandas Python, Merge dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
A = ["word1" : 4 , "word2" : 1]

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=A)
```

Now some new dictionary comes along, Note: that this dictionary doesn't have "word2".

```
B = ["word1" : 4 , "word3" : 1, "word4" : 10]
```

How do I merge B and df such that i get the following results:

```
   word1, word2, word3, word4
0     4     1       0     0
1     4     0       1     10
```

Note:  Row 0 = A and Row 1 = B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpliest is use `list of dictionaries`:

```
A = {"word1" : 4 , "word2" : 1}
B = {"word1" : 4 , "word3" : 1, "word4" : 10}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[A, B])
print (df)
   word1  word2  word3  word4
0      4    1.0    NaN    NaN
1      4    NaN    1.0   10.0
```

EDIT: If need add new row is possible use [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[A])
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(data=[B]), ignore_index=True)
#alternative 
#df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(data=[B])], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   word1  word2  word3  word4
0      4    1.0    NaN    NaN
1      4    NaN    1.0   10.0
```

EDIT1: If need create index from value of `dict` first create column and then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
A = {"word1" : 4 , "word2" : 1, 'index':100}
B = {"word1" : 4 , "word3" : 1, "word4" : 10, 'index':200}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[A, B])
print (df)
   index  word1  word2  word3  word4
0    100      4    1.0    NaN    NaN
1    200      4    NaN    1.0   10.0

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[A, B]).set_index('index')
print (df)
       word1  word2  word3  word4
index                            
100        4    1.0    NaN    NaN
200        4    NaN    1.0   10.0
```

Comment: can this be done after the fact?  i.e: after construction of df

Comment: @SFD  - Yes, it is possible, but not so clean and slowier as first solution.

Comment: @jazrael, thx,   is it safe to, keep track of the indexes,  i.e: have dic somewhere  as follows:  dictionary = {'A' : 0}?

Comment: @SFD - not sure if understand. Do you want define index values?

Comment: @jazrael yes, such that i can keep track of the rows (each row is associated with a document which has a name)

Comment: @SFD - Please check last edit. Also if possible, can you upvote my solution, click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark? Thanks.